# MIKROS Analytics not showing (Unity project)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mikros-analytics, mikros-game-analytics, mikros

I do not see any tracked events on MIKROS Analytics. I have followed all the steps from the [Get Started guide](https://developer.tatumgames.com/documentation/overview).

My app is approved and I already have an "appGameId" and my "apiKey". I am using the Production "apiKey" for now.

Some other information. I have auto initialization enabled under Mikros Settings in the Inspector. I also tested without auto initialization and initialized the MIKROS SDK at app start like this,

```
MikrosManager.Instance.InitializeMikrosSDK();
```

I tried to log a custom event like this,

```
// log events
AnalyticsController.LogEvent("mikros_analytics_test", "parameter", "app_open", (Hashtable customEventWholeData) =>
{
   // handle success
},
onFailure =>
{
   // handle failure
});
```

Any idea why I am unable to see any events on the dashboard? Or what step(s) I am missing?

Comment: Hopefully, the game is up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to other analytic services such as Firebase Analytics or Unity Analytics, MIKROS Analytics queues your events and will send them out in batches. There are certain criteria required in order for the batched events to be sent off.

While both Firebase and Unity can take up to a maximum of 24 hours before events can be viewed on their dashboards, MIKROS has a max time of about 10 hours. However, in most cases MIKROS tracked events will be posted more immediately. The 10 hour timeframe is when the entire batch of events is forced cleared from the queue.

If you want more control of how immediate events are sent off you could force event uploads using flush(). Call the method after you have tracked your events.

```
MikrosManager.Instance.AnalyticsController.FlushEvents();
```

It is not really necessary, but it's an option available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to define the namespaces at the top of your scripts as well.

using MikrosApiClient;
using MikrosApiClient.MikrosAnalytics;

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time after the app is not being used before all events are fully logged. However, you can manually log them by calling:

```
AnalyticsController.FlushEvents();
```

Also make sure you have the following at the top of your script:

```
using MikrosApiClient;
using MikrosApiClient.MikrosAnalytics;
```

Ref: https://developer.tatumgames.com/documentation/log-events